# MySQL procedures - incrementally recalculate rows

Tags: php, mysql, performance, stored-procedures

I have a quite trivial task of calculating budget entries (income/outcome/balance). There can be thousands of entries and I can change any of them in the middle. As the result, all later entries balance must be recalculated.

Right now I am doing it in PHP by iterating through array of all entries, and updating rows that changed. It takes too much time that way - my server stops responding for several minutes.

I suppose that it happens because PHP calls MySQL for every entry update, though for PHP itself this task of array iteration and recalculation is pretty cheap. I think that there must be a way to throw this task at MySQL, so it does the iteration/recalculation/update itself, which might be cheap as well.

I am not an expert in MySQL at all, but I heard that there are stored procedures that might be the cure.

Here is my MySQL (5.5.33) table:

```
CREATE TABLE `entry` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_income` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `income` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outcome` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(20,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Here is my PHP (5.3.27):

```
//...
//$DB is a class for operating DB
$entries = $DB->get_all('entry'); //retrieves all entries from 'entry' table, sorted by date
$balance = 0;
foreach ($entries as $e) {
    if ($e['is_income']) {
        $balance += $e['income'];
    } else {
        $balance -= $e['outcome'];
    }
    if ($balance <> $e['balance']) {
        $e1 = $e;
        $e1['balance'] = $balance;
        $DB->update('entry', $e1); //update the row by doing query('UPDATE `entry` ... WHERE id=' . $entry_id);
    }
}
```

Can you point me the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this in a single SQL `UPDATE` query, no procedure needed.

```
UPDATE entry AS e1
JOIN (SELECT * FROM entry ORDER BY date) AS e2 ON e1.id = e2.id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @balance := 0) AS var
SET e1.balance = (@balance := @balance + IF(e2.is_income, e2.income, -e2.outcome))
```

The user variable `@balance` serves the same purpose as the PHP variable `$balance`. The subquery is needed because MySQL doesn't allow use of `ORDER BY` in a multi-table `UPDATE` query, so you need to join with a subquery that produces the IDs in date order.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar! Is this a complete solution? Just run this query?

Comment: It should be, but I haven't tested it.

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" way is to do the summation when displaying the report, and not store it in the table.

For only "thousands", it should not be a performance problem.

Comment: This is not the best way, because you need to do the time consuming calculation every time the data is displayed. It is better to do it once, save the result, and then just show it.

Comment: Have you measured how long it takes?